# HTML/Javascript Adding text to an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm doing some coding on dreamweaver and encountered a problem while practicing arrays and the like. I tried to make it so when you type something in the box and press the button, it adds the text to the array, allowing the other buttons to display the array. It isn't working and I can't find the right term to google for help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Batman has cancer</title>

        <script>
            var colours = ["Red"," Green"," Blue"]
            function sort() {
                colours.toString
                document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "unsorted array= " + colours;

                colours.sortArray();
                colours.toString();
                document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "sorted arrays= " + colours; 
            }
            function count() {
                document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML="=array size is: " + colours.length;
            }
            function add() {
                colours = colours + getElementById("textBox").innerHTML             

            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Sort" onClick="sort()"/>

        <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Count" onClick="count()"/>

        <input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox"/>

        <input type="submit" name="button3" id="button3" value="Add" onClick="add()"/>

        <p id="result1"></p>
        <p id="result2"></p>
        <p id="Count"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no `sortArray` method for Array

Comment: use `colours.sort()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code:

```js
var colours = ["Red"," Green"," Blue"];
function sort() {
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "unsorted array= " + colours;
  colours.sort();
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "sorted arrays= " + colours; 
}
function count() {
  document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML="=array size is: " + colours.length;
}
function add() {
  colours.push(document.getElementById("textBox").value);             
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Sort" onClick="sort()"/>
<input type="submit" value="Count" onClick="count()"/>
<input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox"/>
<input type="submit" value="Add" onClick="add()"/>
<p id="result1"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
<p id="Count"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot c:

Comment: best suggestion I can make - forget Dreamweaver and learn to code using an editor such as Notepad++ or suchlike. DW may seem easier, but its not as good as understanding the code yourself and it seriously bloats out the code. Just my 2cents worth.

Comment: I would but I'm in school, they have barely any recources for programming here. I'm getting a couple editors when I get home though, notepad++, maybe monodevelop since I already have unity3d

Comment: great that you are doing it at home as well as at school. Just keep learning stuff and never be afraid to ask for help.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark it as answer if it is so. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use .push() to add an item to an array and since you are trying to get a textbox value, it will need to be .value rather than .innerHTML.

```
         function add() {
                var newItem=getElementById("textBox").value;
                colours.push(newItem);            
               }
```

Comment: Still not showing the new text when I press the sort and count buttons

Comment: also you seem to have three input="submit" buttons in there- probably shouldn't - thre is no form to submit - just make them regular buttons with the onclick functions.

Comment: use your console to find what errors are being produced.

Answer (score 0):

Use .push method to insert data after the last index in array

**HTML**

use `onclick` instead of onClick

```
   <input type="submit" name="button3" id="button3" value="Add" onclick="add()"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
  function add() {
                            colours.push(getElementById("textBox").value);  
                        }
```